# Finding predictive power of variables with many missing values

Tags: regression, predictive-models, cart, predictor

I'm aggregating several large surveys with similar/same questions, but from different years. While the questions are often similar in consecutive years and within eras, few questions were asked in every year that the survey was taken. Unfortunately, imputation is not an option for most of the variables.

I'm interested in understanding the predictive power of a good portion of these variables on one of the questions that was asked on every year of the survey.

Does anyone have suggestions for a good methodology? Standard regressions seem to be out -- although maybe someone is familiar with a type of "bagged" regression algorithm, similar to trees.

A tree type algorithm seems like the best fit, although I'm interested if anyone has strong opinions here on the type.

Anything else I should be considering?

Comment: Let's say you have no missing values, what would be your plan for establishing predictive power?

Comment: My goal is to identify some interesting variables that have clear predictive power and that should be highlighted for further study and use in surveys -- so a valid p-value along with its coefficient would be useful. Perhaps testing the movement of r-squared with and without the variable would also help?

Comment: Is the "target question" asked every survey? No missing values in that one?

Comment: Yes -- it's asked on every survey. There are a few missing values, but imputation is relatively painless for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Bayesian regression models can deal with missing values in a principled manner.

For theoretical background, there is a chapter on it in Bayesian Data Analysis by Gelman et al.. A bit easier to read as an introduction is Statistical Rethinking by McElreath, in which missing values are mentioned as one of the topics where Bayesian methods can shine potentially.

Prefabricated solutions like `rstanarm` or `brms` in `R` don't deal with it out-of-the box, allthough there are some running discussions on Github devoted to the topic, but depending on how complicated your model is, you can code it yourself in [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/), or find someone to help you a bit with that.

This is all about the missing values problem, and should set you up to create a solid regression model, also able to handle ordinal questions, and hierarchical structure (within subjects variation). You could then interpret correlation between the answers of the questions

If your question is actually more about analysing "predictive power", which is maybe not that clear defined, things get more complicated, and less well-studied. There are people working on Graphical Models, possibly even with a time-dependency. You can start with this [link](http://jmbh.github.io//Estimation-of-mixed-graphical-models/) for some nice pictures, but this is a large field, if not as mature as standard regression analysis.

Comment: There are far too many missing values to look at imputation as a solution here. Is this what you are suggesting? I skimmed the Statistical Rethinking missing values chapter (at the very end), and it appeared to focus on imputation.

Comment: Yes, allthough, this approach will, in addition to give an approximate posterior distribution for the missing values, also give a posterior prediction for all other coefficients, which is what you are after.